# Siji font not showing up

Tags: fonts

I'm currently setting up a relatively fresh ubuntu+i3 system (started out with Lubuntu 18.04,but upgraded to 21.04 for polybar and replaced basically everything, including WM, File Explorer, Terminal emulator, etc).
I am trying to install Siji for the default polybar.
I tried installing it multiple times, following the instructions on the github page. When installing, the setup in the command line gives me the following instruction, which I can't quite understand:

```
Successfully installed siji.pcf -> /root/.local/share/fonts
  Add the following snippet in your custom startup script that gets executed during xlogin:

    xset +fp /root/.local/share/fonts
    xset fp rehash

  If it already exists then you can skip this step.
```

I do not know what the "custom startup script that gets executed during xlogin" is. Where can I find this script?

I am currently at the status where I can execute view.sh in the font folder (`/usr/share/fonts/siji`), but executing polybar does not find the Siji font (for some weird reason, it says `Loaded font "siji:pixelsize=10" (name=DejaVu Sans, offset=1, file=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf)`).

Also, when I do `fc-list`, I can't find Siji anywhere. How can I get my system to actually see the Siji font, which should be installed in the right location?

Comment: I tried installing again, it did install to the right path for some weird reason, so into ```~/.local/share/fonts/```. Still not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to remove `/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf`.

Source: https://github.com/stark/siji/issues/28

Comment: Thank you so much!! This actually worked, awesome! :)

Comment: @FrancescoSchmitt: Great. Then can you please click the gray check mark to the left of the answer to show others that your question was resolved.